# Given $f:E \to E$ and $f \circ f = f $. Prove that if $f$ is surjective or injective then $f= Id_E$

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions, discrete-mathematics

I could only treat one case:

$f$ is surjective means that for all $y \in E$, there exists $x \in E$ such that $f(x) = y.$

So: $y=f(x)$ and $f(x) = f(f(x))$, this implies $f(x) = f(y)$ and hence $y = f(y)$. And this is true for all $y \in E$. Which means that if $f$ is sujective then $f(x) = Id_E$.

I am stuck in the case where $f$ is injective!

Comment: Compare the images of $x$ and $f(x)$ through $f$

Answer (score 3):

HINT: If $f(f(x)) = f(x)$, then writing $y=f(x)$, note the following: Then $f(y)=f(x)$, and so by the fact that $f$ is injective, $y=x$, or equivalently, $f(x)=x$.